# Rewriting URLs through htaccess with multiple versions of the same page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla

So I did quite a bit of research, but since I'm very new to manipulating .htaccess, I couldn't really find a good answer.

This is my site structure:

**www.kanadax.ca/index.php** is the landing page. This is what Guest users (in Joomla speak) see when they land on the page, before they signup.

**www.kanadax.ca/index.php/anasayfa-2** is the home page for group 1 users, aka non-paying registrants.

**www.kanadax.ca/index.php/anasayfa-3** is the home page for group 2 users, aka paying registrants.

Now ideally, I would like to make all of these just be **www.kanadax.ca/** in the URL bar. The server should know which one to send the user to, but the end user should just see www.kanadax.ca/. I'm not quite sure if this is possible, so this is my first question. If so, what should the .htaccess look like?

If this isn't possible, can I at least take out index.php from each? So they would be

```
www.kanadax.ca/

www.kanadax.ca/anasayfa-2

www.kanadax.ca/anasayfa-3
```

Now of course, anasayfa-2 and -3 are not good practice (anasayfa=home) so I would be very thankful if someone can walk me through removing those if it's not possible to simply make all of these be displayed as www.kanadax.ca/

I hope I was able to explain things clearly but please don't hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: What you're looking to do is not possible using `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess`. Because it is dependent on the log-in state, and the user is only known in Joomla-land, only Joomla can decide what page to display for the same URL. Getting rid of `index.php` is possible, though. I'd put this in an answer but I don't know much about Joomla and couldn't help you in that area.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually solved by enabling `Use URL Rewriting` and `Search Engine Friendly URLs` within the Global Configuration settings for Joomla. Be sure you have a Joomla .htaccess file aswell. There should be a provided htaccess.txt file you can copy to .htaccess if you don't. Additionally, confirm your Joomla cache has been cleared and your browser cache has been cleared before attempting to check for changes.

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated. Before I close this question as answered though, do you know how I can make those home-2, home-3 etc. to just display as home for both user groups? All relevant pages have that number for each group (e.g. tier 1 has all links as home-2, blog-2, faq-2 etc. and tier 2 has home-3, blog-3 etc.) which looks ugly. Is that possible through Joomla as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect your `index.php` page to your **domain**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ http://www.kanadax.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

althogh you cannot redirect user to a specific page because info are stored in joomla session and you cannot make any rule or condition in `htmlaccess` basing on that.